# Celery worker - ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, celery

Celery connection breaks when long running task is executed.
I am using amqp as broker and redis as backend.

Celery is running on remote host, the command I am using for celery worker is as follows

```
pipenv run celery worker -A src.celery_app -l info -P gevent --without-mingle --without-heartbeat --without-gossip -Q queue1 -n worker1
```

The error log is as follows:-

```
[2020-09-09 14:26:46,820: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Couldn't ack 1, reason:ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\kombu\message.py", line 131, in ack_log_error
    self.ack(multiple=multiple)
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\kombu\message.py", line 126, in ack
    self.channel.basic_ack(self.delivery_tag, multiple=multiple)
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\amqp\channel.py", line 1394, in basic_ack
    spec.Basic.Ack, argsig, (delivery_tag, multiple),
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\amqp\abstract_channel.py", line 59, in send_method
    conn.frame_writer(1, self.channel_id, sig, args, content)
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\amqp\method_framing.py", line 189, in write_frame
    write(view[:offset])
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 305, in write
    self._write(s)
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socket3.py", line 534, in sendall
    return _socketcommon._sendall(self, data_memory, flags)
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socketcommon.py", line 392, in _sendall
    timeleft = __send_chunk(socket, chunk, flags, timeleft, end)
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socketcommon.py", line 321, in __send_chunk
    data_sent += socket.send(chunk, flags)
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socket3.py", line 515, in send
    return self._sock.send(data, flags)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Unable to understand why this error is occurring.

Comment: Experiencing a similar issue. How do you know that the connection breaks because of a long running task? Any updates?

Comment: @RobZ, my background task runs for around 2 hours. By modifying data to run the task for 45mins or 1 hour it was not breaking, but when it goes beyond that I was getting this error. So the alternative I found was that I am checking celery status in a while loop at particular time intervals, and once the task is complete, loop is exited. This solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The timeout of redis is set to 0, which means it will not be disconnected. Then this situation will not occur. At least this is what my project looks like. I hope it will be helpful to you.